# AVCaptureAudioDataOutput Is Not Calling AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate.captureOutput

Tags: swift, macos, avfoundation, avcapture

When I run AVCaptureSession with AVCaptureAudioDataOutput, the delegate is not being called.
What step am I missing?
I appreciate your help!

```
import Cocoa
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: NSViewController, AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let session  = AVCaptureSession()
        
        guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInMicrophone, for: .audio, position: .front) else { return}
        do {
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device:device)
            if session.canAddInput(input) {
                session.addInput(input)
                let output = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()
                output.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: .main)
                if session.canAddOutput(output) {
                    session.addOutput(output)
                }
                
                session.startRunning()
                
                print("Running")
                
            }
        } catch {
        }
    }
    
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        print(sampleBuffer.numSamples)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you get any devices? I tried to build your code but didn't get any devices. Anyway, you can look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49598691/macos-swift-capture-audio-with-avcapturesession) and also this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37890791/avcapturevideodataoutput-captureoutput-not-being-called). Also, one thing I can guess, not sure though. Put your capture session variable

```
let session  = AVCaptureSession()
```

outside of viewDidLoad.

Comment: Awesome! just Putting session  outside viewDidLoad fixed it!!! Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I'm glad it helped.

Comment: Since it helped you, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem.