# macOS: How to capture audio input levels in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, volume, avcapturesession, levels

On macOS, I am looking for the best way to capture audio input levels from a microphone using Swift.

This article is along the lines of what I am thinking, but am not sure how to go about processing the sample buffers to get the volume levels:

[macOS/swift Capture Audio with AVCaptureSession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49598691/macos-swift-capture-audio-with-avcapturesession)

Am I on the right track, or looking at this the wrong way?

Answer (score 3):

I was close on this but did not realize it.

For the AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate captureOutput callback, the parameters also include a value for AVCaptureConnection.  This connection has a parameter named audioChannels which provide the peakHoldLevel and averagePowerLevel properties.

Problem solved.